# Issue installing angular in mac - getting ng common not found

Tags: angular-cli

manojseth@manojs-air ~ % node -v
v16.13.2
manojseth@manojs-air ~ % npm -v
8.1.2
manojseth@manojs-air ~ % npm install -g @angular/cli

added 183 packages, and audited 184 packages in 10s

found 0 vulnerabilities
manojseth@manojs-air ~ % ng version
zsh: command not found: ng
manojseth@manojs-air ~ %

Comment: Please at least have the courtesy to do a [basic search for the error message](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=command+not+found%3A+ng) before posting a new question. This question has been asked and answered here several times before. A thorough search is part of the effort we expect users to make before asking here.

Answer (score 0):

I try after some time with this following command and getting issue fixed

to fix my issue below command works

```
npm link @angular/cli
```

and finally go for create project

```
ng new project_name
```